# Dynamicly updating datatable columns if a new column was added to the database

Tags: vb.net, datatable, visual-studio-2005

The problem now is that if I alter table to add a new column to the database, clear the datatable, fill the datatable, the new column is nowhere to be found. Even if I restart the program the number of columns in the datatable remains static as it was the last time it was refreshed though the Visual Studio.
The only way I know how to refresh the table to show the new columns is to press modify on the select query of the datatable adapter, press configure and press finish. Then it updates. But that's not really a solution for me.

The example is this:
There is table with controls names in every language.
The rows are the different controls, the columns are the different languages (plus ID and the generic control name ofc).
In order to add a new language the user must add a new column. After the ALTER TABLE query, I can't display this even after refreshing the grid. This is due to the datatable created with the Visual Studio interface having static columns. And this is where my problem is at.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem:
I created a datatable through code and every time a column was added, I updated it with a SqlDataReader through datatable.Load(SqlDataReader). Then I refresh the grid and it's updated.

Also, to manualy handle dynamic insert, delete and update queries I looped through the datatable(For Each temprow As DataRow In datatable.Rows) and checked the datatable.row(number).RowState

1. DataRowState.Modified - UPDATE. I got the number of columns in the table and used them to loop and make a dynamic query using column headers and cell values.
2. DataRowState.Added- INSERT. Same thing as update except with the INSERT syntax.
3. DataRowState.Deleted - DELETE. The most simple one. Only needed the ID cell value.

Answer (score 0):

Use ALTER command ..

```
Dim commandString as String = "ALTER TABLE " + TableName + " ADD COLUMN " + FieldName + " " + Type

Dim Conn As OleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection( your connection )

Conn.Open()

Dim Command As OleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(commandString, Conn)

Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

Conn.Close()
```

Comment: I know how to add a column. I don't know how to refresh the datatable/grid to reflect the changes.